# Linux: Apache Two domain name pointing to the same remote ec2 cloud server but different folders

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vhosts

I have an Amazon EC2 linux 14.04LTS server running basic LAMP stack and I have two domains `4techgroups.com` and `ecommercejiban.shop`.

While `4techgroups.com` is purchased from Godaddy, `ecommercejiban.shop` hasn't been purchased.

My conf files on my EC2 Server on `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` are `001-4techgroups.conf` and `002-ecommercejiban.shop`

My `001-4techgroups.conf` looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.4techgroups.com
    ServerAlias 4techgroups.com 
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/4tech

    <Directory "/var/www/html/4tech">
       AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/4techerror.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/4techaccess.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And My `002-ecommercejiban.shop` looks like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.ecommercejiban.shop
    ServerAlias ecommercejiban.shop
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/jibancommerce

    <Directory "/var/www/html/jibancommerce">
       AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/jibancom-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/jibancom-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I Restarted the server on my EC2. 
Now since I didn't purchase the `ecommercejiban.shop` domain name I went to my home local ubuntu 14.04 machine and added the following on my hosts file at `/etc/hosts`

```
52.24.182.161  ecommercejiban.shop
```

I restarted servers many times and I am able to visit the 4techgroups.com site but I cannot visit my ecommercejiban.shop. But I already edited my local hosts file to point to that server any way. so why is my 2nd domain ecommercejiban.shop not working.

Adding nslook ecommercejiban.shop output from my local machine

```
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ecommerce-jiban.shop
Address: 92.242.132.24
```

i dont think there is any related symlinks in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Jun 18  2016 000-default.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   37 Dec 30 20:45 003-ecommerce.conf -> ../sites-available/003-ecommerce.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   53 Oct 20  2016 006-drupal-theme-installation.conf -> ../sites-available/006-drupal-theme-installation.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   47 Nov 12  2016 007-portfolio-otherport.conf -> ../sites-available/007-portfolio-otherport.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Nov 13  2016 008-student.conf -> ../sites-available/008-student.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   43 Jan 16  2017 014-drupal-practice.conf -> ../sites-available/014-drupal-practice.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   43 Feb 26  2017 017-drupal-property.conf -> ../sites-available/017-drupal-property.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Apr 23  2017 019-hacka.conf -> ../sites-available/019-hacka.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   37 Aug 27 12:24 025-multisite.conf -> ../sites-available/025-multisite.conf
```

Comment: What is the IP when you do `nslookup ecommercejiban.shop` on your system?

Comment: Hey I added the nslookup output on my question

Comment: Are there any conf files/symlinks in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`?

Comment: @DusanBajic I guess OP knows about that: "_and I am able to visit the 4techgroups.com site but I cannot visit my ecommercejiban.shop_"

Comment: Let's wait and see :)

Comment: Hi guys the nslookup added earlier was completely wrong one. the ns lookup and symlink listed on the edit now is from my local machine, you meant from  my local machine right and not from my ec2 server.

Comment: Can you set the virtual host on your local machine for the ec2 server?